How to add an item to the bottom of a sortable list in Alpine Js?
I have the following simple code.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Alpine Plugins -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/sort@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Alpine Core -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body x-data="{
    order:1,
    items:[]
}">
    <div>
        <ul x-sort>
            <template x-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <li   style="padding:1rem;"  x-sort:item="index"  x-bind:x-ignore="true"  x-text="item"></li>
            </template>
        </ul>
        <button @click="items.push(order);order+=1">Add Item</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



How should I modify the code above so that a new item is always added to the bottom of the unordered list after I reordered the items?
